# Logic with numbers

Tags: rust, prolog, clpfd

In SWI-Prolog, I can write that

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

and(A,B):- A , B.
```

And I get:

```
?- and((X #= 4), (X #> 3)).
X = 4.

?- and((X #= 4), (X #< 3)).
false.

?- and((X #< 4), (X #> 3)).
false.

?- and((X #< 5), (X #> 3)).
X = 4.

?- and((X #< 5), (X #< 3)).
X in inf..2.
```

Is it possible to write that in Rust using std::cmp ?
For now, I'll settle for the answer true, false, without instantiating the X variable.
Thank you for any tip.

Comment: Rust is not a logic language, so you can't do that with the base language no. std::cmp is regular run-of-the-mill functions operating on values.